# How to find the equillibrium points using Jacobian and Hessian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, lagrangian-formalism

Given that I have Jacobian and Hessian matrices of three particles interacting with each other in a harmonic trap through Coulomb's law in a 2D plane, how do I find the equilibrium points of them (I know it should be a triangle)?

Comment: Is the system total potential of the form $U=\left(\sum_{k=1}^3A|\mathbf{r}_k|^2\right)+B\left(|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_3|^{-1}+|\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_3|^{-1}+|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^{-1}\right)$? There is an obvious parametrization which affords a dimensionality reduction from 6 to 1, at which point you can just take a 1-dimensional derivative and set equal to zero.

Comment: Assuming that the original function is positive, then finding equilibrium points, which amounts to finding the zeros of the field, actually amounts to minimizing the field. Now use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Functions_of_more_than_one_variable

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I was actually thinking on the same lines and yes the potential is of the form you have shown. Can you please explain how i can parametrize it?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus What will be the form of jacobian and hessian matrices after parametrization?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I am unable to figureout whats that obvious parametrization!

Comment: I'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

With a potential surface $$U=\left(\sum_{k=1}^3A|\mathbf{r}_k|^2\right)+B\left(|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_3|‌​^{-1}+|\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_3|^{-1}+|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^{-1}\right),$$ a guess parametrization is to fix the particle coordinates to form the vertices of an equilateral triangle with a radius $R$, ie
$$\mathbf{r}_k=\left(R\text{cos}\left(\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right),R\text{sin}\left(\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right)\right).$$

This reduces the number of dimensions from 6 to 1, at which point you can stick this guess into the potential $U$ and take the derivative with respect to radius $R$ and set equal to zero.

In Mathematica:

```
r[k_] := R {Cos[2 \[Pi] k/3], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/3]};
norm[v_] := Sqrt[v.v];
U = Refine[A (norm[r[1]]^2 + norm[r[2]]^2 + norm[r[3]]^2) + B (1/norm[r[1] - r[3]] + 1/norm[r[2] - r[3]] + 1/norm[r[1] - r[2]]), Assumptions -> R > 0];
Solve[D[U, R] == 0, R]
```

giving $$R= \frac{\sqrt[3]{B}}{\sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[6]{3} \sqrt[3]{A}}.$$

So the question is, is this correct? It's a critical point of the 1-d potential, which incidentally looks like this:

```
Plot[U /. {A -> 1, B -> 1}, {R, 0.02, 5}]
```

[image]

But is it also a minimum of the higher-dimensional potential surface? Evaluating the gradient and computing the eigenvalues of the Hessian at the previously-determined minimum yields

```
{x1, x2, x3} = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
UHighDim = A (norm[x1]^2 + norm[x2]^2 + norm[x3]^2) + B (1/norm[x1 - x3] + 1/norm[x2 - x3] + 1/norm[x1 - x2]);
Refine[(D[UHighDim, {{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 1}] /. Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f} -> Flatten@{r[1], r[2], r[3]}]) /. R -> B^(1/3)/(2^(1/3) 3^(1/6) A^(1/3)), Assumptions -> {R > 0, A > 0, B > 0}]
Eigenvalues@Refine[(D[UHighDim, {{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 2}] /. Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f} -> Flatten@{r[1], r[2], r[3]}]) /. R -> B^(1/3)/(2^(1/3) 3^(1/6) A^(1/3)), Assumptions -> {R > 0, A > 0, B > 0}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
>
> {6 A, 3 A, 3 A, 2 A, 2 A, 0}

Since $\nabla U=\mathbf{0}$ at our previously guessed equilibrium configuration, the guess equilibrium configuration is also a critical point of the higher-dimensional energy surface. In addition, the Hessian is positive semidefinite, which means that the configuration is stable to second order (since everything curves upwards in higher-dimensional space about that point), with the exception of the mode of motion which has eigenvalue zero, which just corresponds to a uniform rotation of the triangle. So our guess is correct.

You can also calculate the harmonic frequencies of the trap from this, if needed.